# Installation of Report Server 2014 freezes

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssrs-2014

Asked by:
Avatar of Renato G Sabo

Hi, im having a issue trying to install SSRS 2014 on my Windows 2012 Standard Server.

I was having trouble trying to install SQL 2014 Standard (downloaded from my partner account), and was failing. So i started it again, installed core features, plus manager, but without SSRS and it installed without issues.

When after i try to add SSRS to the instance, it freeze at same point. The installation runs thru, until it goes to sqlRsConfigAction_install_confignonrc_cpu64. In this moment, the installation freezes and dont go anywhere further. If i cancel the installation its the same, it remains frozen, i need to kill the process.

When i check it seen the SSRS is installed, in one attempt it even started the service but it was clearly not running as it should. When i try to use the repair feature of installation it says it couldnt be repaired because it never was properly installed.

When i check the logs, at program files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150406\SQL_rs_Cpu64_1.log

It seen the installation was completed, but its not working at all. I was thinking this was somewhat related to IIS, since there is nothing configured on IIS when i open IIS manager. I tried to install with IIS stopped, and also with FastCGI stopped (used for PHP), and also the mysql server stopped, but nothing solved the issue.

Anyone have any idea what can i do? Reinstalling the server isnt a option, it would require a lot of work to put the mySQL/php website working back, and also several other issues reconfiguring filezilla server that is being used for other services, plus i cant allow those services to be suspended. I need SQL Server to publish a asp.net application that is currently running on other server.

MSI (s) (D4:88) [15:30:33:880]: Note: 1: 1707 MSI (s) (D4:88) [15:30:33:880]: Product: SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services -- Installation completed successfully.

```
MSI (s) (D4:88) [15:30:33:880]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services. Product Version: 12.0.2000.8. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 0.

MSI (s) (D4:88) [15:30:34:912]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (D4:88) [15:30:34:912]: MainEngineThread is returning 0
MSI (s) (D4:7C) [15:30:34:912]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (D4:7C) [15:30:34:912]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
=== Logging stopped: 06/04/2015  15:30:33 ===
MSI (s) (D4:7C) [15:30:35:021]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (D4:7C) [15:30:35:021]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (D4:7C) [15:30:35:021]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (D4:7C) [15:30:35:021]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2
MSI (s) (D4:7C) [15:30:35:100]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035
MSI (s) (D4:7C) [15:30:35:100]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2
MSI (s) (D4:7C) [15:30:35:100]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (D4:7C) [15:30:35:342]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (s) (D4:40) [15:30:35:342]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
MSI (c) (38:10) [15:30:35:342]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (38:10) [15:30:35:342]: MainEngineThread is returning 0
=== Verbose logging stopped: 06/04/2015  15:30:35 ===
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue minutes ago - found out, that installer freezes, when another windows installer (any) is running at the same time. Check your process-manager and kill the other installers running. This also seems to be the case for trying to enable or disable Windows features (e.g. enabling IIS, et.c.) while installing SSRS and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Surely IIS is running. You are running a project and forgot to install sql server. You were smart enough to identify the error and detected you didn't install sql server, so you started doing that. But with IIS running. Close the project that is running. You don't have to reinstall sql server cause all it's features were installed already. Install management studio to test the installation of sql server, and then you can run visual studio.